# PHP SplFixedArray bugged or slow performance?

Tags: php, performance

So I made this simple script to test the `SplFixedArray` object to see how good it performs.

Traditional method with array

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
$start    = microtime(true);
$memStart = memory_get_peak_usage(true);
$loop     = 1000000;
$array    = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < $loop; ++$i) {
    $arr       = ['a'];
    $array[$i] = $arr;
}

$end    = microtime(true);
$memEnd = memory_get_peak_usage(true);
echo 'Time: ' . ($end - $start) . "\n";
echo 'Mem: ' . ($memEnd - $memStart) / 1024 / 1024 . 'Mb';

//Display: Time: 0.037514925003052 Mem: 28Mb
```

With `SplFixedArray`

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
$start    = microtime(true);
$memStart = memory_get_peak_usage(true);
$loop     = 1000000;
$array    = new SplFixedArray($loop);

for ($i = 0; $i < $loop; ++$i) {
    $arr       = new SplFixedArray(1);
    $arr[0]    = 'a';
    $array[$i] = $arr;
}

$end    = microtime(true);
$memEnd = memory_get_peak_usage(true);
echo 'Time: ' . ($end - $start) . "\n";
echo 'Mem: ' . ($memEnd - $memStart) / 1024 / 1024 . 'Mb';

//Display: Time: 0.21888899803162 Mem: 142Mb (slower by 5x)
```

From the documentation, isn't `SplFixedArray` promise to have better performance and memory? Why is it behaving that way. So exactly in what situation should we use it?

Comment: Micro-optimizations like this tend to be a silly rabbit hole to go down. Three hundredths of a second over 100k iterations? I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @ceejayoz I updated the question with 1 millions. It's micro-optimizations or not depends on how you see it. I don't want the script to consume 1Gb of memory when I can't optimize it with some line of code to make it 100Mb.

Comment: You still create multiple `SplFixedArray` objects instead of **just one**. Please read again my post with the explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SplFixedArray` is a special type of object that in general behaves as an array, but with the following restrictions:

1. Unlike the regular array - `SplFixedArray` has fixed size.
2. Unlike the regular array - `SplFixedArray`'s keys can be only integers.

Because of those two characteristics - the implementation of the methods on arrays for the `SplFixedArray` can be faster.

As for your example - note that in the second example you created 100000 new `SplFixedArray` objects (unlike the first example, where you created only 1 array).

Taking your example - when removing the creation of the new `SplFixedArray` inside the loop, and just setting the value `a` to each element of the array - this is what I get:

```
$start = microtime(true);
$memStart = memory_get_peak_usage(true);
$loop = 100000;
$array = new SplFixedArray($loop);


for ($i = 0; $i<$loop; $i++) {
    $array[$i] = 'a';
}

$end = microtime(true);
$memEnd = memory_get_peak_usage(true);
echo "Time: " . ($end - $start) . "\n";
echo "Mem: " . ($memEnd - $memStart)/1024/1024 . 'Mb';

// Time: 0.0023539066314697 Mem: 2Mb
```

> note that I changed to microtime

One more important thing to remember here - the "faster array implementation" that is mentioned in the documentation is related to the array-like-functions that can be used on the `SplFixedArray` object.

Comment: I changed `'a'` into `['a']` or even `$arr = ['a']; $array[$i] = $arr;` The result is still the same. Version used `SplFixedArray` cost more time and memory

Comment: Please read the entire explanation. The "faster implementations" is regarding the specific array-related methods - sorting/splitting/accessing elements. Don't test only one thing - test everything. Read/write are completely different, and also - there is a huge difference between small and large objects. Also - in my example the memory was 2Mb (and yours was 4Mb).

Comment: I will read, ty for suggestion. I also test with 1 million of loop. The object version took 142 Mb of memory versus 28 Mb.

Comment: your second example (which is wrong test) or my test?

Comment: I updated the question with good test. Still show standard array outperform object array (mostly in term of memory)

Answer (score 1):

`SplFixedArray` is more efficient *for the specific use cases it was designed for*. If it was faster and used less memory for everything, it would simply be implemented as the default for all arrays, and indeed PHP 7 automatically chooses between multiple implementations depending on how you use each array.

The idea of having a *fixed length* array is that by setting the length in advance, the engine doesn't need to guess how much memory to allocate, and rearrange memory when you make the array longer or shorter. So to compare them, we need to use a benchmark where that would make a difference, such as starting with an empty array and adding a million elements to it:

```
$loop     = 1000000;
$array    = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < $loop; ++$i) {
    $array[] = 42;
}
```

vs

```
$loop     = 1000000;
$array    = new SplFixedArray(1000000);

for ($i = 0; $i < $loop; ++$i) {
    $array[$i] = 42;
}
```

Note that I'm only ever creating one array, or one `SplFixedArray`, as creating many small arrays is not the case we're testing.

On a PHP 7.2 box I have to hand I get the following benchmarks:

- Array: 220ms, 32Mb
- SplFixedArray: 211ms, 15Mb

On PHP 5.6, the difference is even more striking, showing how much the internal array implementation has improved in recent versions:

- Array: 450ms, 138Mb
- SplFixedArray: 320ms, 53.75Mb

Like most benchmarks, this probably doesn't resemble real-world code, but it shows one scenario where using an `SplFixedArray` would give a definite advantage.

You could play around and probably find even larger differences, e.g.

- Assigning to elements at random, rather than in order, so it's harder for PHP to guess the final length.
- Removing elements as well as adding them.
- Reading from the array, or iterating over it with `foreach`

Conversely, we can simplify your test case to see where the slow down is, by not assigning to an outer array at all:

```
$loop     = 1000000;

for ($i = 0; $i < $loop; ++$i) {
        $array    = new SplFixedArray(1);
}
```

This takes 1.5 seconds or more to run on my PHP 7.2 machine, vs 0.2 seconds if I write `$array = []`. Clearly, there is a cost to creating new `SplFixedArray` instances which needs to be taken into account when choosing whether to use them.

For "multi-dimensional arrays", this is likely to be a significant factor, because there is no way to pre-allocate the multiple dimensions, you have to create new instances for each item in the outer array. A different structure could be implemented to optimise that case, but none is built into PHP as of version 7.4.

Comment: This works because you are using an array of 1 dimension. If you use 2 or more dimension like I did, the result is different.

Comment: @ThanhTrung Read the first sentence of this answer. `SplFixedArray` is optimised _for a particular scenario_, and your test doesn't demonstrate that scenario. Note that neither PHP arrays nor `SplArrayObject` instances can be "multi-dimensional" in a strict sense (i.e. they don't lay out any kind of matrix in memory), they can simply have elements that happen to be other arrays, or other `SplArrayObject` instances. The main cost in your benchmark is running `new SplFixedArray(1)` a million times; and that's simply not the usage it's optimised for.

Comment: Ok so your point is when we do `$array = []` in the loop it doesn't create a million of time an array? What does it creates then, one unique array in the memory?

Comment: @ThanhTrung No, your example creates a million arrays and a million `SplFixedArray` objects, and compares the speed and memory. Creating a million arrays turns out to be faster and less memory-intensive than creating a million `SplFixedArray` objects, but that shouldn't be surprising, because creating a million single-element arrays isn't how `SplFixedArray` is intended to be used. It feels like you're still looking for reasons your original benchmark is giving "the wrong result", but it's not; it's just giving a result that's not very relevant to what that object is for.